# Eapol_test showing timestamp for Access-Request and Response messages

Tags: freeradius

Do you know if there is someway to use Eapol_test to test a remote server (by creating a script that is running it in a loop every X seconds) and append the timestamp of the Access-Request message sent, and Access-Accept/Reject messages that are received?
I can only get execution time by using the "time" command in the console, but this is not the time of the RADIUS server to process and respond, but the time the OS took to process the whole command. what I want to get is the time it takes to get the Access-Accept response to monitor delay in authentication from remote locations with high circuit delays from time to time, so to match any connectivity issue during initial association or roaming with a potential delay.

This is what I'm using this command:

```
time ./eapol_test -r0 -c ./wpa_supplicant.conf -a 10.1.1.1 -p 1812 -s Password!23
```

I'm looking for timestampos for at least these messages (or all of them) as if I were seen them on packet captures.

```
Sending RADIUS message to authentication server
RADIUS message: code=1 (Access-Request) identifier=0 length=114
(...)
Received RADIUS message
RADIUS message: code=3 (Access-Reject) identifier=0 length=44
(...)
```

OR

```
Sending RADIUS message to authentication server
RADIUS message: code=1 (Access-Request) identifier=0 length=114
(...)
Received RADIUS message
RADIUS message: code=11 (Access-Challenge) identifier=0 length=90
(...)
Received RADIUS message
RADIUS message: code=11 (Access-Challenge) identifier=3 length=1490
(...)
Sending RADIUS message to authentication server
RADIUS message: code=1 (Access-Request) identifier=11 length=270
(...)
Received RADIUS message
RADIUS message: code=2 (Access-Accept) identifier=11 length=324
```